# Why does setting 'mi' in LS_COLORS effect postgresql and python tab completion?

Tags: ls, colors, autocomplete

So I have a custom `LS_COLORS` setup, and in that I have the following:

```
mi=05;01;33:
or=05;01;33:
```

`mi` is for missing files on the right column when in ls's list view, and `or` is for a missing files in normal ls mode, or on the left in list mode. The above sets it so that both flash in bright yellow. I set it like that because I thought having it flash would be the most obvious way to alert myself to a missing link, which works great.

But the problem is when I run the python in interactive mode and ask for tab completion, e.g. `import re` then `re.[tab key]`. Instead of just getting a normal list whatever is in `mi` in `LS_COLORS` gets applied to the suggestions. So I end up with a screen full of blinking text which makes it borderline impossible to read at any reasonable rate.

The same thing happens when I use tab completion in the postgresql interactive mode console. Exactly the same as python. Most other programs or similar are fine though, and bash completion is fine.

Are these programs using `ls` to format their output? I've currently just changed `mi` back to something else to get around the problem, and it doesn't really matter because I can still see broken links via `or`. But I'd be really curious to know why this is happening and if I can stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[GNU readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html)** is being used, as can be confirmed by [listing the
default modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858123):

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules.keys()
dict_keys([...,'readline', 'atexit', 'rlcompleter'])
```

Readline, by its turn, uses `LS_COLORS`. From `man 3 readline`,

> **colored-stats (Off)**
> If set to On, readline displays possible completions using different colors
> to indicate their file type.  The color  definitions  are  taken  from  the
> value of the LS_COLORS environment variable.

If you are not convinced, go back to the interactive python session and type

```
>>> a<TAB><TAB>
abs(     all(     and      any(     as       ascii(   assert   async    await
>>> import readline
>>> readline.parse_and_bind("set colored-stats off")
>>> a<TAB><TAB>
abs(     all(     and      any(     as       ascii(   assert   async    await
```

After disabling colored-stats, the suggested completions (`bs(`, `ll(`, etc.)
should be on normal color of the terminal. The prefix `a` still inherits
color from `LS_COLORS` and you can likewise disable it with

```
readline.parse_and_bind("set colored-completion-prefix off")
```

Comment: Oh cool information. Thanks. I think it's probably easier and will work across multiple programs if I just remove 05 from mi then.

Comment: @LeviH Glad to help. Yeah, I think that is the best solution, but it should well be possible to set some kind of `.pythonrc` that runs a series of commands before starting the interactive session. See in `man python3` `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable.